# PC can't boot even from a live USB - probably corrupted bootloader or MBR

Tags: linux, windows, grub, bootloader, mbr

While getting rid of dual-booted Linux I tried recovering Windows 7's bootloader with EasyBCD. (one-click process described in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWapcEQZExs&t=110))

However, something went wrong and now GRUB is gone as it should be, but Windows 7's bootloader probably wasn't recovered correctly. When I try to boot into Windows it gets stuck forever on the screen with the Windows logo. It seems to get stuck there even when booting from a Windows 7 repair USB I created.

When I try to boot Linux Mint from live USB it says

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes...

drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

I also tried booting Slitaz as a more lighweight distro but it can't load the desktop environment either.

Is there anything I can do at this point to boot into any OS?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows 7 DVD boot into Windows Recovery and bring up a CMD window, you should be able to use 'bcdboot C:\Windows' to recreate the C:\Boot directory as well as the C:\Boot\BCD file. (Assuming C:\ is where the installation directory is).

If you didn't delete the original Windows 7 hidden 100MB partition you could use 'bootrec /rebuildbcd' instead.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. By "I don't have Windows repair CD" I meant I don't have any Windows 7 CD or DVD. And really not any quick way to get one.

Comment: I'm sorry. I must have missed that part. ;) Without any way to get into a Windows environment on the local machine it's not easy to rebuild the BCD store. You could attach the HDD to another Windows machine to build a new BCD but that's rather excessive. Last time this happened to me I was unable to fix the issue from Ubuntu and had to download a copy of Windows from my MSDN account. Have you another Windows computer you could use to attempt to create a BCD?

Comment: Well, I have this old Windows XP computer I'm currently at but I don't really feel very comfortable disassembling 2 computers (especially because I haven't done anything like that before and no idea how I would start). I actually don't really care about the Windows installation much now and would prefer overwriting the bootloader with GRUB and loading to Linux if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't think of anything you can do without a working Vista or above OS (be it on another computer or from a CD/USB/WinPE environment). As for reinstalling GRUB2, it's relatively easy to do from a Linux Live CD and there are plenty of guides out there. (http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.Uqc8CJBdV38) Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, the problem is I can't even boot into Linux with Live CD or USB at this point.

Comment: What is the brand of laptop? To get to at least boot, there was a mention earlier about a hidden partition. I will build on this. There is a keystroke combination particular to each manufacturer of computer that will get it to boot into its recovery (hidden) partition. If all your hardware is in good working order it will get you back to a working unit. It is likely it will delete all your data. If you can get a live cd to boot, pull your data first.

Comment: Just seen the comment about the live cd, sorry. Get your hardware tested. Use MemtestX86, it is downloaded free and can be burned to a CD. It is bootable. Also do the same for your hard drive, each manufacturer has their own testing software that is a free download and is burned to a CD as well.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you dont have a win7 repair DVD... You could ask someone with windows 7 to let you burn a DVD with it. Also, the repair DVD ISO's are floating around online. Not sure if it's legal to post a link though, so I won't.

If you can get your hands on a repair DVD or install DVD, use the repair utilities command prompt to run `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.

You really do *need* a windows repair or install DVD.

*Might* have a failed RAM chip. Try replacing your current RAM with new pieces. One of them may have failed.

Source: Happened to an old Dell Inspiron 1420 I once owned, long ago.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. I couldn't boot using Live USB of Windows 7, 8, Ubuntu 14.04 and Boot-repair iso. Finally, I could format my drive and reinstall everything only when booting with Ubuntu 10.10. Hope this hint may help someone in the future.

Cheers.